# Existence of complex derivative at a point

Tags: complex-analysis

I found an exercise in the first volume of the book "Theory of functions of a complex variable" by A. I. Markushevich. I need a hint to solve it, please don't post a complete solution.

Let  $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$ with $u$ and $v$ differentiable at $z=z_0 = x_0 +iy_0$.
Prove that from the existence of $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0} \mathrm{arg}  \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}  $ it follows that also  $\lim\limits_{z\to z_0}   \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0}$ exists.